# Экранированный символ в Python

Tags: python

У меня есть json вот в таком виде

```
body = {
    "formId": "636089ed66530325bab09399",
    "collectionId": "636087eb4c39561ca395a6c9",
    "objectName": "yui_3_17_2_1_1667270623491_48585",
    "form": "{\"text-b30bfd68-443e-4388-8a22-a240719d9093\":\"test#1234\",\"text-c8fe475c-83f0-495c-9746-9973e6272439\":\"@test\",\"email-189c2570-f5ba-450f-92a3-dfe43e504641\":\"test@gmail.com\"}",
    "pagePermissionTypeValue": 1,
    "pageTitle": "Home",
    "pageId": "636087eb4c39561ca395a6c9",
    "contentSource": "c",
    "pagePath": "/"
}
```

Собственно в чем суть. Я хочу отправлять post реквесты с этим телом, но в чем заключается загвоздка. У меня есть текстовый файл и я хочу заменять через цикл данные test#1234, @test, test@gmail.com

```
creds = open('creds.txt')
for line in creds:
    line = line.rstrip().split(':')
    first_input = line[0]
    second_input = line[1]
    third_input = line[2]
```

Но экранированные символы не дают этого сделать, ибо я пытался через f-строку, к примеру

```
 "form": f"{\"text-b30bfd68-443e-4388-8a22-a240719d9093\":\"{first_input}"
```

и даже так

```
 "form": "{\"text-b30bfd68-443e-4388-8a22-a240719d9093\":\f"{first_input}"
```

Пытался полностью удалить слэши и попробовать отправить так запрос, но без этого не получается, выдаёт 400 ошибку

Как я могу это исправить или может какой- то другой способ использовать, подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: `r"json"` а так? Или просто поменяй скобки с двойных на одинарные

Comment: JSON надо разбирать как JSON. Не надо работать с ним как с сырым текстом. `import json` и так далее.

Answer (score 0):

Примерно как-то так:

```
creds = open('creds.txt')
for line in creds:
    first, second, third = line.rstrip().split(':')
    form = {"text-b30bfd68-443e-4388-8a22-a240719d9093":first,"text-c8fe475c-83f0-495c-9746-9973e6272439":second,\"email-189c2570-f5ba-450f-92a3-dfe43e504641":third}
    # body питоновский словарь
    body = {
    "formId": "636089ed66530325bab09399",
    "collectionId": "636087eb4c39561ca395a6c9",
    "objectName": "yui_3_17_2_1_1667270623491_48585",
    "form": form,
    "pagePermissionTypeValue": 1,
    "pageTitle": "Home",
    "pageId": "636087eb4c39561ca395a6c9",
    "contentSource": "c",
    "pagePath": "/"
    }
    # post-запрос body словарь отправляется на сервер в виде json
    res = requests.post(url, json=body)
```

Answer (score 0):

При использовании `f-строк` фигурные скобки нужно экранировать не бэкслэшем, а ещё одной такой же фигурной скобкой:

```
first_input = "test#1234"
print(f"{{\"text-b30bfd68-443e-4388-8a22-a240719d9093\":\"{first_input}\"}}")
```

Вывод:

```
{"text-b30bfd68-443e-4388-8a22-a240719d9093":"test#1234"}
```